# Why would my twilio portion of the program work on my laptop but not my pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Currently using twilio sms library so that the the data collected from my house can be sent to my phone.  When I ran it from my laptop it worked fine, but after pip importing it onto my Pi and trying to run it I still got the exception:

```
ImportError no module named 'twilio'
```

This seems so simple, but I have spent a long time reading through documentation and know I'm just missing something super basic.

```
from twilio.rest import Client

client = Client("***************", "**************")

client.messages.create(to="++*******",
                       from_="*******",
                       body="Pi says hi")
```

Thanks a ton for anyone who helps me out!
Note: I'm using python 3 for both and raspbian as the OS.

Comment: Doesn't look like you have installed the twilio module on your Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, then the problem is likely that you used `pip`. `pip` will install modules for `python2`. If you want to install to a `python3` env, you need to use `pip3`.

```
pip3 install twillio
```

Note:

If you don't already have pip3 installed, you'll need to do that as well.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip3
```

Comment: @KyleGong: If that solved your problem, please consider accepting the answer :)